# nginx proxy server not able to upload files greater then 1 MB

Tags: nginx

Below is my nginx conf I am using (nginx is a docker container)- Nginx is used as a proxy server to all backend api servers. When I am tried to upload file I am getting error if size is greater then 1 MB. Tried all possible solution given but cloudn't resolve. Any help would be useful.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name abcd.dev;
    #rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
    charset utf-8;
    keepalive_timeout 300s;
    gzip on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

    client_body_in_file_only clean;
    client_body_buffer_size 10M;
    client_max_body_size 10M;

    sendfile on;
    send_timeout 300s;

    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_request_buffering off;
    proxy_buffer_size 10M;
    proxy_buffers 32 4m;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 10m;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 1024m;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 10m;

    proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
    proxy_read_timeout 300s;
    proxy_send_timeout 300s;


    proxy_set_header HOST $host;

    #X-Forwarded-Proto header gives the proxied server information about the schema of the original client request (whether it was an http or an https request).
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    #The X-Real-IP is set to the IP address of the client so that the proxy can correctly make decisions or log based on this information.
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

    #The X-Forwarded-For header is a list containing the IP addresses of every server the client has been proxied through up to this point.
    #In the example above, we set this to the $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for variable.
    #This variable takes the value of the original X-Forwarded-For header retrieved from the client and adds the Nginx server's IP address to the end.
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    error_page 404 /custom_404.html;
        location = /custom_404.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                internal;
        }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /custom_50x.html;
        location = /custom_50x.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                internal;
    }

    location / {
      location ~ ^/(uploads/|vendor/|images/|img/|javascript/|js/|css/|stylesheets/|flash/|media/|static/|robots.txt|humans.txt|favicon.ico) {
            proxy_pass http://ui-service;
      }
      if ($domain) {
        set $args $args&nethumUrl=$domain;
        proxy_pass http://ui-service$uri$is_args$args;
      }
      proxy_pass http://ui-service$uri$is_args$args;

    }
...........
}
```

I am able to upload any files which is less then 1MB but bigger files not getting uploaded. Getting below error -

```
error 2017/03/02 06:52:37 [error] 38#38: *89 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream
```

Comment: Can you set the config `client_max_body_size` param inside location block & try again ?

Comment: The error message says that connection is reset by your backend. Can you show logs from your java backend?

Comment: note that while proxying nginx uses http/1.0 by default. You said below that uploading to your java app directly works fine - lets try to explicitly use http/1.0 in your test client or use proxy_http_version 1.1 to make sure your test is fair. And yes any logs from your java app would be helpful otherwise we can only guess what's happening out there

Answer (score 1):

What is your php.ini setting on `upload_max_filesize`? Also try to add `client_max_body_size 10M;` in your http directive (in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf), as well as in the location directive.

Comment: I am not using php. Its a proxy server which send request to Java server and I have a limit of 10M there as well. If I upload directly to my Java server it work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem of a kind. It was solved by fine tuning of the next (behind nginx) web server. However, here is some settings in `http` section that can help

```
default_type  application/octet-stream;
sendfile        on;
keepalive_timeout  300;
client_max_body_size 100m;
gzip  on;
```

Comment: also possible to disable the check on client body size by setting `client_max_body_size` to `0` (see https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size)

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that connection is closed by your backend (Java server). Check it logs to figure out problem source.

Comment: the path is nginx->node-proxy->java app

Comment: @Ananda Can you show logs of node-proxy and java app? It looks like source of the problem is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I have nginx as a docker container and many web-servers behind nginx.
I have docker-compose.yml
with volumes mapping directive:
"- ./conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro"
and with separate "conf" files at ./conf.d for each web-server.
I solved the issue by adding

```
client_max_body_size 100M;
```

to server section of every "conf" file.